# Are YouTube videos Web Content Accessibility Guidelines 2.0 compliant?

Tags: video, youtube, accessibility

When embedding a YouTube video on a organisation's website, what is necessary to make this accessible and WCAG 2.0 AAA compliant?

It's my understanding that closed captions (toggleable subtitles) are a necessity. While YouTube can auto-generate these captions, it can have mistakes which reduce your compliance. If these captions are edited for correctness, is that enough?

Or is a full transcript required?

Answer (score 1):

From my reading of the WCAG 2.0 guidelines, closed-captions are enough to meet some of the guidelines at **Level A**, however **Level AAA** (and possibly **AA** also?) appear to require a text alternative that is *not time-based*, meaning you need to provide a text transcript that the user can read at their own pace (unlike captions, which forces the user to read quite quickly).

(Think of a person new to English who can only decipher words very slowly.)

Refer to: https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/#media-equiv

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the need for captions, which might be met by YouTube's auto-captioning, the other issue with meeting WCAG 2.0 (or 2.1) at AA or AAA is the [requirement under criterion 1.2.5](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/media-equiv-audio-desc-only.html) to provide audio descriptions if your video track contains any extra information or context needed to understand the audio.

Unfortunately, as of this reply YouTube does not support a separate audio description track without additional software layered on top. So the answer is that, in general, a YouTube video without extra support can be accessible only at the A level, not AA or AAA.